# Android VideoView SplashScreen

Tags: android, android-videoview, splash-screen

This is my splash.java, and I am using my videoView as the contentView. Is there any way that I can center the video inside the videoView which is the contentView?

Or what is the better thing to do?

```
package com.android;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Splash extends Activity
{
    VideoView vidHolder;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try
        {
            vidHolder = new VideoView(this);
            setContentView(vidHolder);
            Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash);
            vidHolder.setVideoURI(video);
            vidHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
            {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    jump();
            }});
            vidHolder.start();

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            jump();
        }
    }

    private void jump()
    {
        if(isFinishing())
            return;
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideo"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice: you didn't ask for it, but your code is from an example seen elsewhere that will feature the infamous black flash before and after the video. You need to add `vidHolder.setZOrderOnTop(true);` to avoid that (after `#setVideoUri`).